How does Alchemist's Fire interact with Spite?
We were having an encounter with Spite from Cutthroat Caverns recently and came onto an interesting situation, heres the scenario:
Spite has 20 hp.
Initiative 1 had their attack cancelled.
Initiative 2 had an attack for 20, and also tipped their Alchemist fire.
Initiative 3 had an attack for 25.
Alchemist fire specifically mentions "turn", which for me means you can't do it until your initiative is up, but also it doesn't specify if the tip happens before or after your attack hits.
In my mind you can interpret this situation in two ways:

Initiative 2 kills the boss when tipping Alchemist fire, since the damage happens immediately and isnt subject to Spite's damage cancellation. Initiative 2 wins.

Initiative 2's damage now totals 50, and initiative 1's damage is 25. Initiative 2's damage is canceled by Spite. Initiative 1 wins.


So I guess my questions are:

When does Alchemist fire damage hit?
Does it only hit on the player's turn who tipped?
Does it stack with your Set Attack?
Is it subject to Spite's damage queueing/cancellation, or does that only apply to regular attacks?

Any other unmentioned rules re: Alchemist Fire would be helpful, as theres very little detail about it in the rules!
